# set_text function does nothing in calabash-android 0.4.20

Tags: android, ui-automation, calabash

After I upgrade calabash-android from 0.4.18 to 0.4.20, the set_text function in my script does nothing, I can't set text for the textfield Usename and Password.
The script still works fine with Calabash-android 0.4.18. After exploring the library source code, I found out that there are differences between set_text function of library version 0.4.18 and 0.4.20. Here are 2 snippets of code :

C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\calabash-android-0.4.18\lib\calabash-android\operation.rb

```
def set_text(uiquery, txt)
raise "Currently queries are only supported for webviews" unless uiquery.start_with? "webView"

uiquery.slice!(0, "webView".length)
if uiquery =~ /(css|xpath):\s*(.*)/
  r = performAction("set_text", $1, $2, txt)
  JSON.parse(r["message"])
else
 raise "Invalid query #{uiquery}"
end
end
```

---

C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\calabash-android-0.4.20\lib\calabash-android\operation.rb

```
def set_text(uiquery, txt)
view,arguments = uiquery.split(" ",2)
raise "Currently queries are only supported for webviews" unless view.downcase == "webview"

if arguments =~ /(css|xpath):\s*(.*)/
  r = performAction("set_text", $1, $2, txt)
else
 raise "Invalid query #{arguments}"
end
end
```

Does anyone have the same problem? Please help me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick for ya

```
query("insert your query", setText: "insert text here")
```

for example:

```
query("EditText id:'username'", setText:"user@example.com")
query("EditText id:'password'", setText:"secret_password")
```